# SSMTP and PHP sending mail through different domainds(sub-domains)

Tags: linux, email, debian, php, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up SSMTP on my Raspberry PI(Raspbian Wheezy(Debian ARM port)) Model B,
Right now I can send mail through the console just fine, actually getting the mail aswel.

The problem is when I try to send mail through PHP, it seems to send it to another domain/sub-domain.

The console sends it to mail.justcandan.com:587, which works,
PHP sends it through mail.pi.justcandan.com (standard port 25), while is should be the same as the console.

Heres one line that is repeated in the log

```
May  6 22:27:24 plaatjescollectie sm-mta[312]: r46AfkKJ025954: to=<www-data@pi.justcandan.com>, delay=11:45:38, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=6420000, relay=mail.pi.justcandan.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred
: Connection timed out with mail.pi.justcandan.com.
```

And heres my the sendmail_path part of my php ini(/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini)

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/sendmail -t -i -f pi@justcandan -r stefan@justcandan.com"
```

So what am I doing wrong? I don't understand how console sendmail works just fine, but in php it's not working.

Okay I got it working, had my sendmail_path wrong, sendmail is located in /usr/sbin/ not /usr/bin. But now I still got a problem, even though my mail is physically "sent" it never get to my mail box, weird.

This is my mail.log, when sending through php:

```
May  7 05:43:02 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: Creating SSL connection to host
May  7 05:43:02 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: SSL connection using RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
May  7 05:43:03 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: Sent mail for pi@justcandan.com (221 vserver104.axc.nl closing connection) uid=33 username=www-data outbytes=378
```

This is my mail.info, when sending through php:

```
May  7 05:43:02 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: Creating SSL connection to host
May  7 05:43:02 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: SSL connection using RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
May  7 05:43:03 raspberrypi sSMTP[4426]: Sent mail for pi@justcandan.com (221 vserver104.axc.nl closing connection) uid=33 username=www-data outbytes=378
```

All of the other mail. files in /var/log are empty.
Apache2 logs are only returning a favicon not found, but that doesn't matter.

EDIT:
Appearantly, my Pi wasn't responding, and after 10 minutes, I started to get the mails.
So I guess I fixed this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so to fix this I had to to set sendmail_path in php.ini to

`"/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f pi@justcandan -r stefan@justcandan.com"`.

After that I editted /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf and changed the rewrite domain to `justcandan.com`

After that I added an alias in `revaliases` in `/etc/ssmtp/`

`www-data:my@mail.com:mail.domain.tld:587`

after restarting apache, and waiting till my PI responded, it send me the mail.